# Objective-C: NSLog passing value (pass-by-reference versus pass-by-value)

Tags: objective-c, pointers, object, nsstring, nslog

I have a question about the use of the NSLog function in Objective-C while developing for iOS. 
I am used to C++ syntax so this is a bit new.

In the first case we see that the value of the pointer is passed in the function:
[image: NSLog with value of pointer]

In the second case we see that the pointer itself is passed in the function:
[image: NSLog with pointer adres]

Does this mean that the %@  parameter takes a pointer to the object,
and all other (%i, %c, %d, %f, u) take a value. I guess it has something to do with primitive datatypes versus an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does this mean that the %@ parameter takes a pointer to the object

Yes, it takes a pointer to an Objective-C object, which can be of type `NSString` or any other `NSObject` derived type; in the latter case, the `description` method is used to convert the object to a string. You can think of it as the equivalent to `%s` for Objective-C strings.

This is how the `%@` placeholder is described in Apple does:

> Objective-C object, printed as the string returned by descriptionWithLocale: if available, or description otherwise. Also works with CFTypeRef objects, returning the result of the CFCopyDescription function.

Have a look at [this Apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/FormatStrings.html) for more details and also ["String Format Specifiers"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW1).